# When did 'ut'/'uþ' from Old English and Middle English become 'out'?

Tags: etymology, old-english, middle-english

When was the transition of the word form 'ut'/'uþ' to 'out'?
I'd like to know about the frequency or first attestations.

Comment: This would be better as two separate questions. Questions asking for external resources are usually handled on the ELU Meta site.

Comment: The OED would be a good start for the history of "out". Beyond that, search academic bibliographical databases to see if there are any papers on the subject.

Comment: I'm removing the second question to keep the question focused. Please refer to the etymology section of [our list of resources](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2573/191178) for more information. The answers you get here might also help you see some of those resources in use.

Comment: Nobody knows. All one might get is the first printed reference, centuries after it was first spoken. By the time a dictionary noticed it, it was established in some places if not all.

Answer (score 2):

This transition was a regular consequence of the Great Vowel Shift:

> ut → out, hus → house, tun → town, hlud → loud.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) has an approximate timeline.

The transition went through several intermediate stages (scholars disagree on exactly what these intermediate stages were). Wikipedia seems to say it was pronounced *ut* in 1400, and reached something like the modern *out* in 1700.

There's no point trying to give an exact date, because some regions were undoubtedly still pronouncing it [ut] (*oot*) when other regions had already started pronouncing it [out] (*oat*). I suspect the transition from [ut] → [out] took something like a century to complete, and at the end of this century the following change (to [ɔu]) had already started.

Comment: "There's no point trying to give an exact date, because some regions were undoubtedly still pronouncing it [ut] (oot)" - indeed, and some regions still do :)

Comment: …& I cannot hope to spell how 'out' is pronounced in Belfast. 'aoyt' is the best I can do, but it's not right.

Comment: I am actually more interested in the written conventions, trying  to determine a terminus post quem of an image reproduce from a lost manuscript. I suppose that the written change would be later than that in pronunciation.

Comment: @trespda The written form usually follows from pronunciation. So during the time of the shift, there were probably different spellings depending on who was writing it.

Answer (score 0):

OED **out**:

> Out was formed by a merging of two distinct words, Old English ūt and ūte (apparently already confused in Old English).
>
> (i) Old English ūt is cognate with Old Frisian ūt, and was originally only an adverb,
>
> (ii) Old English ūte is cognate with Old Frisian ūte, Old Saxon ūta, ūte,  (translating ancient Greek ἔξω outside)
>
> These two forms became merged in later Middle English.